# libcontainer - system programmers perspective

Tags: docker, containers

I am a newbie go programmer, with system programming background,trying to dissect libcontainer. I am pretty familiar with name spaces and control groups . I am interested in knowing  how exactly libcontainer leverages these features to create a container.

Logically speaking someone has to call **clone system call** with NEW_NS_FLAGS.But I cant find where this clone system call being called!!

Documentations says that , one has to use **factory interface** , to create container. I see that it simply does the validation job for id and config and create directory with 700 permission.

**container.start** , supposed to be creating a new name space , also does not call clone system call.

If some one can tell me , how container creation works in terms of system calls , it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I too am interested in this, and have only just started looking at the code in depth.

I believe what you are looking for is done in nsexec.c which reads (or rather gets passed via a unix socket using netlink messages) the config for the namespace setup, which then calls clone() twice.

In the child process, I believe it calls setns() to create or set the namespace to the new values.

The whole thing is not entirely clear to me, but from what I seem to understand so far, the process using libcontainer execs itself with a arg of "init" which becomes PID 1 in the new container, and it looks like this new process does a few things in C as well as go to setup the container.